# System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException - in OleDb Connection using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbconnection

We are connecting to Access DB via OLE DB Connection and it was working till last office update. Now after getting latest version of MS Office

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: 'External component has thrown an exception.'
```

My build configuration is x86 and Access database engine also 32 bit. So, as a solution i have repaired the access engine and it starts working. But, i am able to reproduce the issue with below code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var _conStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\test.accdb; Persist Security Info=False";

            try
            {


                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    using (var con = new OleDbConnection(_conStr))
                    {
//This Call 1
                        con.Open();
                    }
                });


                using (OleDbConnection OleDbConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(_conStr))
                {


// This Call 2
                    OleDbConnection.Open();
                }


                Console.WriteLine("Hello World 1!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World 2!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

In the call 2 only i am getting this exception. But, most confusing thing is, how does it has the issue with latest update. How come its working if i repair access database engine.

What is the fix for above code? I used many tasks in my application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as its causing issue only in multi threading. So that, we have handled the issue in Thread safe calls.
Please refer below.

```
class Program
{
    static object synObj = new object();

    static string _conStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\test.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1234567;";

    static OleDbConnection _oleDBObject;
    public static OleDbConnection OleDBObject
    {
        get
        {
            lock (synObj)
            {
                if (_oleDBObject != null && _oleDBObject.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {

                    return _oleDBObject;

                }
                else
                {
                    _oleDBObject = new OleDbConnection(_conStr);
                    _oleDBObject.Open();
                    return _oleDBObject;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        try
        {

            int i = 0;

            while (i < 10)
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {

                    // Connection inside task
                    var con = OleDBObject;
                    Console.WriteLine("Inside Task -" + i.ToString());

                });   

                i++;

                Console.WriteLine("Task -" + i.ToString());

            }

            // Connection outside task
            OleDbConnection OleDbConnection = OleDBObject;


            Console.WriteLine("Hello World 1!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


}
```